Optimize moving average function python
I am creating a function in python to filter data using a moving average, here is my current code:
def movingAvgR(data):
    data = data.to_numpy()
    filteredData = []

    for i in range(len(data)-11):
        y = (data[i]+data[i+1]+data[i+2]+data[i+3]+data[i+4]+data[i+5]+data[i+6]+data[i+7]+data[i+8]+data[i+9]+data[i+10]+data[i+11])/12
        filteredData = np.append(filteredData,y)

    return filteredData

How can I make it so I do not have to hard code the amount of indices I want to include in my average?
I tried using a for loop to concatenate a string with the linear combination of the indices I request, but I was having type errors.

here is a modified version of the code you have, though there is a better implementation.
def movingAvgR(data, window_size):
    data = data.to_numpy()
    filtered_data = []

    for i in range(len(data) - window_size + 1):
        window = data[i:i+window_size]
        avg = np.sum(window) / window_size
        filtered_data.append(avg)

    return np.array(filtered_data)

here is a more concise version of your implementation:
import numpy as np

def moving_avg(data, window_size):
    return np.array([np.sum(data[i:i+window_size]) / window_size for i in range(len(data) - window_size + 1)])

here is a better and faster implementation you should use which is based on the fact that a moving average is loosely a convolution:
import numpy as np

def moving_avg_cumsum(data, window_size):
    cumsum = np.cumsum(np.insert(data, 0, 0))
    return (cumsum[window_size:] - cumsum[:-window_size]) / window_size


You can slice the ndarray as follows:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def movingAverageR(data: pd.DataFrame, n=12) -> np.ndarray:
    na = data.to_numpy()
    ma = np.array([])
    for i in range(len(na)-n):
        y = np.average(na[i:i+n])
        ma = np.append(ma, y)
    return ma

df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(25)))

print(movingAverageR(df))

Output:
[ 5.5  6.5  7.5  8.5  9.5 10.5 11.5 12.5 13.5 14.5 15.5 16.5 17.5]

